# How to use browser history with components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have following code:

```
const [showChild1, setShowChild1] = useState(false)
const [showChild2, setShowChild2] = useState(false)

        <ParentComponent>
          {showChild1 && <Child1 />}
          {showChild1 && <Child2 />}
           ....
      </ParentComponent
```

Suppose I am viewing `Child2` in my browser, but I want to go back to see `Child1`. How can I use the browser's back and forward buttons to navigate between conditionally rendered components? As of now when i click on the back button im pushed to path `/`.

Comment: Use something like [React router](https://reactrouter.com/).

Comment: But will react-router has any effect if both components show up conditionally without changing the url path?

Comment: @PRSHL — No, but "using it" means "Use it instead of `useState`"

Comment: I've a doubt to clear. At the beginning, let's say you're **directly viewing** `/child1`. Does that mean when you click **forward button of the browser** , it should direct to `/child2` path ? If so, it's not possible, current path that you're in (which is `/child1`) is the last route included in history stack. Therefore, forward button won't be enabled.

Comment: If you really won't to have navigation through views, then why don't you think of using a navigation panel inside your application rather than having browser back & forward buttons ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add event listeners to the global window object. The event name is "popstate", here is the code example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', yourEvent);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', yourEvent);  
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Can u maybe implement this in codesandbox as an example?

Answer (score 0):

use onpopstate event to handle browser navigation options.